# Textarea keydown trigger shift key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which = 16; //shift key

$('textarea').on('keydown',function(){
    $('textarea').trigger(e);
});
```

I have a textarea and I want to auto add <kbd>Shift</kbd> key press when user typing.

(I don't want to detect <kbd>Shift</kbd> key press, I want to trigger <kbd>Shift</kbd> key)

anyone how to do this?

Comment: From your code, it looks like you are trying to add make everything they enter comes in with the shift pressed. So if the user presses "34g" the textbox would show "#$G" Is that correct?

Comment: yes thats what i try to achieve

Comment: no you can't do that... you can trigger an keydown event but it may not reflect the default behaviors of user keypress

Comment: dont need to worry about reflect, we can just detect if user not press, we trigger

Answer (score 0):

As an example in [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
// Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
var e = jQuery.Event( "keydown", { keyCode: 16 } );
// trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 16
jQuery( "body" ).trigger( e );
```

With *16* is code of SHIFT key

To get another key code ref [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).